# Slf4j with Log4j does not print wrapped exception (caused by) when wrapper exception has a message

Tags: java, exception, logging, log4j, slf4j

First example:

```
public class Main {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            throw new RuntimeException(new NullPointerException("NPE"));
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            logger.error("Error:", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Error:
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException: NPE
    at Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

In the second example we just add a message to the `RuntimeException` also:

```
throw new RuntimeException("RTE", new NullPointerException("NPE"));
```

Output:

```
Error:
java.lang.RuntimeException: RTE
    at Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

Why is `NullPointerException` not logged in this case?

Note: `e.printStackTrace()` prints both exceptions in both cases:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: RTE
    at Main.main(Main.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: NPE
    ... 1 more
```

Versions:

```
slf4j-api: 1.7.12
slf4j-log4j12: 1.7.12
log4j: 1.2.17
```

Comment: Which version of slf4j and log4j you are using?

Comment: i tried your code with slf4j 1.7.12 and log4j: 1.2.13 and here is what i got `Error:
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException: NPE
 at com.test.Test.main(Test.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: NPE
 ... 1 more` And `Error:
java.lang.RuntimeException: RTE
 at com.test.Test.main(Test.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: NPE
 ... 1 more`

Comment: @Sanjeev Thanks. I found out what the cause of the issue was. It is `log4j.throwableRenderer=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedThrowableRenderer` that I did not notice in the `log4j.properties` at first. Once removed, the full stack trace is printed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I noticed that in the `log4j.properties` file I'm using there is the following line:

```
log4j.throwableRenderer=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedThrowableRenderer
```

It seems to be causing the `caused by` elements to be omitted when the exception is logged.

Once removed, the full stack trace is logged.

Comment: Great to know. But that follows up a doubt in my mind, I am not using this line(`log4j.throwableRenderer=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedThrowableRenderer`) in my `log4j.properties` and still the entire stacktrace is not logged. What changes shall i make?

Answer (score 7):

Giving it a possible try using all the docs and debugging I could, I hope this helps in whatever way it can :

```
  @param message the message object to log.
  @param t the exception to log, including its stack trace.
  public void error(Object message, Throwable t)
```

So both your cases are including the stack-trace of the RuntimeException thrown by the statement of code. Not much of a difference.

**Case 1** : ***`throw new RuntimeException(new NullPointerException("NPE"));`***

Quoting from the [RuntimeException Java-Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html#RuntimeException()) and [NullPointerException Java-Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)

```
public RuntimeException(Throwable cause)
```

> Constructs a new runtime exception with the specified cause and a
>   detail message of `(cause==null ? null : cause.toString())` (which
>   typically contains the class and detail message of cause). This
>   constructor is useful for runtime exceptions that are little more than
>   wrappers for other throwables.

---

```
public NullPointerException(String s)
```

> Constructs a NullPointerException with the specified detail message.

---

So that possibly answers the first part of your question where **`java.lang.RuntimeException`** is thrown during execution which is *caused* by the `new NullPointerException` but as `cause==null` evaluates to *false* the `cause.toString()` is printed i.e **`java.lang.NullPointerException`** and now since this exception itself has a message passed that follows as **`NPE`**

*Note : You have mentioned the cause as NullPointerException in your code.(hence `cause==null` evaluates to false)*

**Case 2** : ***`throw new RuntimeException("RTE", new NullPointerException("NPE"))`***

```
public RuntimeException(String message, Throwable cause)
```

> Constructs a new runtime exception with the specified detail message
>   and cause. Note that the detail message associated with cause is not
>   automatically incorporated in this runtime exception's detail message.

---

In which case you end up getting **`java.lang.RuntimeException`** being thrown with a message **`RTE`** since your cause is a child of `RuntimeException` itself and the parent is caught first, it gets executed and the child is not reached in this case.

Comment: Nice analysis, thanks. Any way to make log4j print the entire stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

**There are 2 issues.**

> 1. Why is NullPointerException not logged in this case[throw new RuntimeException("RTE", new NullPointerException("NPE"));]?

### Ans:

Actually `SLF4J has no impact on that case`. It is pure JVM issue. In JVM, it is required to compute every passed parameter before function call. If you follow this 2 examples, you can easily understood that issue.

**Example 1:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            throw new RuntimeException(new NullPointerException("NPE"));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException: NPE // Here, "java.lang.NullPointerException: NPE" - this portion is used as message according to RuntimeException
    at Main.main(Main.java:3)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: NPE
    ... 1 more
```

Here, `"java.lang.NullPointerException: NPE"` - this portion is used as message according to RuntimeException which one is also generated from another exception [NullPointerException(String s)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html#NullPointerException(java.lang.String))

**Example 2:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            throw new RuntimeException("RTE", new NullPointerException("NPE"));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: RTE // Here "RTE" is used as message
    at Main.main(Main.java:3)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: NPE
    ... 1 more
```

Here `"RTE"` is used as message.

In your code, you have used 3 times exceptions. That's not good coding.

---

> 2. Why e.printStackTrace() prints both exceptions in both cases?

`e.printStackTrace()` prints this throwable and its backtrace to the standard error stream. It prints a stack trace for this Throwable object on the error output stream that is the value of the field `System.err`
As your output is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: RTE
    at Main.main(Main.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: NPE
    ... 1 more
```

- The **first line** of output`["java.lang.RuntimeException: RTE"]`
  contains the result of the toString() method for this Throwable
  object.
- **Remaining lines** represent data previously recorded by the method [fillInStackTrace()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#fillInStackTrace())
- The **backtrace for a throwable** with an initialized, non-null cause
  should generally include the backtrace for the cause. The format of
  this information depends on the implementation. For your clear
  understanding, go through the backtrace example below:

  ```
  HighLevelException: MidLevelException: LowLevelException
          at Junk.a(Junk.java:13)
          at Junk.main(Junk.java:4)
  Caused by: MidLevelException: LowLevelException
          at Junk.c(Junk.java:23)
          at Junk.b(Junk.java:17)
          at Junk.a(Junk.java:11)
          ... 1 more
  Caused by: LowLevelException
          at Junk.e(Junk.java:30)
          at Junk.d(Junk.java:27)
          at Junk.c(Junk.java:21)
          ... 3 more
  ```
- **"... 1"**

  These lines indicate that the remainder of the stack trace for this
  exception matches the indicated number of frames from the bottom of
  the stack trace of the exception that was caused by this exception
  (the "enclosing" exception).

### Resource Link:

1. [What printstacktrace does?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace())
2. [SLF4J-Log4J does not appear to have disabled logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8643654/slf4j-log4j-does-not-appear-to-have-disabled-logging?rq=1)

---

For `SLF4J`, you can go through

1. [sysout-over-slf4j](http://projects.lidalia.org.uk/sysout-over-slf4j/) module redirects all calls to `System.out` and
   `System.err` to an SLF4J defined logger with the name of the fully
   qualified class in which the `System.out.println` (or similar) call
   was made, at configurable levels.
2. [idalia SLF4J Extensions](http://projects.lidalia.org.uk/lidalia-slf4j-ext/) allows logging at a level determined at
   `runtime` rather than `compile-time`.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem when I was using Slf4j Logger in my Apache Spark application running on cluster mode. As I found out problem in my case was caused by JVM optimization related to `OmitStackTraceInFastThrow` which was basically not printing whole stack just top level error without any details.

In your case this might be hiding error message from `NullPointerException`. Try adding this argument to JVM `-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow` when starting your application and let us know if it works.

Comment: No, `printStackTrace` contains the full trace in both cases. It is logging that does not print the full trace.

Comment: Yes in my case regular java `e.printStackTrace` was printing full trace as well but Slf4j wasn't so I used provided JVM argument and it solved it for me but I'm not sure it will solve your problem

Comment: I tried it, it does not work. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion.